# SP13: Add+ AppearsBut Form Does not Open

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, custom-list, calendar, custom-actions

So, I ran across this issue in the past but the Add+ did not appear for any of the calendar dates.  This is a different issue.  The Add+ does appear for all dates but on a certain date range the Add+ appears but when you select it - nothing happens.  Example.  It will appear and the form will come up for dates from 1st to 15th of October.  But for 16th to 20th of October the Add+ appears in the calendar but when I click on the it the form does not open.

Has anyone experienced this issue?  I thought its pretty odd when it works perfectly fine for the other dates on the calendar.  FYI.  I am using Windows 10/Edge.